# Aligning the baseline grid to guides and margins in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, grids

When I create a grid using the "Create Guides" feature in InDesign (I want rows, columns and margins), I can not figure out how to align the baseline grid with the guides.

Is there a mathematical equation to figure out how to do it?

For example, if I have a letter sized page with 3 rows and 3 columns with a gutter on 1p and 1p margins, how do I create a baseline grid that conforms to this grid system that I created?

Answer (score 1):

Baseline Grid Settings are under Indesign/Preferences/Grid. You can set the line height and the top starting point. To match your row grid, the row height must be divisible by your line height (eg. row height 150pt, line height 15pt).